# how to use geometry datatype to postgres table?

Tags: database, geospatial, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I have setup a postgres database(version 9.1) and trying to create a table capable of storing st_geometry with the following query :

```
CREATE TABLE sensitive_areas (area_id integer, name varchar(128), zone st_geometry);
```

But I am getting the error as follows :

```
ERROR:  type "st_geometry" does not exist
```

Do I need to configure my postgres installation further to enable geometry data type .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE sensitive_areas (area_id integer, name varchar(128), zone geometry);
```

You should have `PostGIS` installed in you db for this to work.

Answer (score 11):

The correct type name is `geometry`. If you are you are using PostGIS 2.0 you can use a typmod:

```
-- If you haven't done so already
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

-- Make a table of Polygons, using long/lat coords
CREATE TABLE sensitive_areas (
    area_id integer primary key,
    name varchar(128),
    zone geometry(Polygon,4326)
);
```